# Les viticulteurs « sont (en) bio » ?

Tags: sens, prépositions, stylistique

> [...] à peine plus de 2 % des viticulteurs champenois *sont en bio*.
>   (ds. [*Lapresse.ca*](https://www.lapresse.ca/gourmand/alcools/202002/12/01-5260643-champagne-moet-hennessy-arretera-lutilisation-des-herbicides-fin-2020.php))

S'agit-il du même sens que sans la prépositon (« sont bio ») ? Peut-on expliquer techniquement/précisément la différence, qu'est-ce qu'ajoute la prépositon [*en*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en/0) ici, est-elle requise pour signifier ce qu'on veut dire, s'agit-il d'être une chose ou d'être d'une manière ; est-ce une différence stylistique ou sémantique ou les deux, est-ce une réduction pour un tour différent et le cas échéant pourquoi ?

Comment: "sont bio" voudrait dire que physiquement ils sont (certifiés) bio, ce qui serait absurde pour ce cas. "En bio" pour exprimer le fait qu'ils sont en (production) bio

Comment: @Vega Stp ajoute une réponse. Dans une réponse on parle de l'agriculture, dans une autre de la production qui respect les conditions ou qui s'est déplacée vers l'agriculture bio et tu parles d'une simple ellipse d'une partie d'un complément.

Comment: On peut aussi remplacer "en" par "dans le" - "Ils sont dans le bio". Que ce soit  l'agriculture ou la production, les deux sont sous-entendues

Answer (score 3):

*[Être bio](https://www.francetvinfo.fr/economie/emploi/metiers/agriculture/agriculture-etre-ou-ne-pas-etre-bio_2625940.html)*, c'est participer au mouvement bio qui consiste à éliminer les pesticides, engrais chimiques, OGM, etc.

*[Être en bio](https://www.bioenlorraine.org/les-dmarches)*, c'est ici sensiblement la même chose. La préposition n'est donc pas requise. Elle signale que la production des viticulteurs est "en bio", respecte les conditions requises.

Comment: D'accord, je ne voulais pas dire _faire dans le bio_ avec le sens péj. dont tu parles mais bien plutôt _faire de l'agriculture biologique_ et je me demande si le _en_ témoigne de cette « ellipse/réduction » ou reformulation. Le déplacement, ok. je n'avais pas perçu ça comme ça, intéressant, comme _passer de X à Y, passer en_.

Answer (score 2):

Ce ne sont pas les vignerons qui sont *bio*, c'est leur façon de cultiver. La phrase pourrait s'écrire :

> [...] à peine plus de 2 % des viticulteurs champenois *pratiquent une agriculture* bio.

Comment: Dans « Être XY », l’usage peut remplacer XY par n’importe quel nom qui regroupe des personnes qui s'identifient à ce groupe : être Basque, être chrétien, être communiste,  … pour les agriculteurs être bio :  https://french.stackexchange.com/a/41253/848

Comment: Peut-être que cette espèce d'ellipse ou reformulation ou je ne sais comment dire explique ma perception. Ou plus généralement mon champ d'emploi pour le verbe _mener_ est plus restreint. Je ne sais pas exactement si _mener_, _mener en_, ou _être en_ participent également de ma perception particulière dans ce domaine.